# Umbraco, SEO and ImageGen.ashx

Tags: iis, seo, umbraco

I have created site on Umbraco, for display image gallery on my site I using ImageGen plugin for umbraco.
In my last step of development I deside to make SEO analysis for site. (SEO plugin for IIS from Microsoft)
I got error 
***There are too many references for this resource.**The URL 'localhost/ImageGen.ashx' has been crawled more than 500 times. This usually indicates an infinite loop in redirection logic.* 
I disable link to ImageGen.ashx in robox.txt file, but what i need to do if I link to this images is very important ? I want to show them to different search engines (Google, bing etc).

Is SEO plugin for IIS work correct ?

Comment: Do you know if it is an infinite loop or if you do indeed have more than 500 unique references to that ImageGen?

Comment: This is not  infinite loop from my point of view, maybe SEO plugin think like this or calculate total count of images. I don't really know. But It is looks like infinite loop :) How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider hiding *ImageGen* altogether from the user/search engines by using a little **url rewriting**.

Most of the times, ImageGen is used to resize images to a handful of predetermined picture dimensions. Let's assume for your site you need to have a *thumbnail*, a *mobile* version of the image, a *standard* image as well as the *highres* version. You may contribute the highres version to Umbraco and use ImageGen to generate the other images. Instead of

```
http://localhost/ImageGen.ashx?image=/media/2153/picture.jpg&width=150&height
```

for the thumbnail, you could use

```
http://localhost/images-thumbnails/2153/picture.jpg
```

and rewrite that url into the first one.

For the other versions, the publicly visible url could be:

```
http://localhost/images-mobile/2153/picture.jpg
http://localhost/images-standard/2153/picture.jpg
http://localhost/images-highres/2153/picture.jpg
```

By using url's like this, you also add some more information to the image which may gets used by the search engines, and you can easily block for example highres images from being indexed.

Comment: Thanks. this solution is very cool for developers. but if customer want to upload any images to site and don't want resize them to 3 different version or he can decide to change image size in any time. That the best way to do it ?